# Replace value based on the values of 2 nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyXMLTree xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Node1>X</Node1>
   <Node1Ext>Y</Node1Ext>
</MyXMLTree>
```

I would like to have an XSLT to transform the XML to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyXMLTree xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Node1>X</Node1>
   <Node1Ext>1</Node1Ext>
</MyXMLTree>


If Node1 == 'X' and Node1Ext != 'X' then 
    Node1Ext = '1'
else if Node1 != 'X' and Node1Ext == 'X' then 
    Node1Ext = '2'
else if Node1 == 'X'and Node1Ext =='X' then
    Node1Ext = '3'
EndIf
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What if `Node1 != 'X' and Node1Ext != 'X'`?

Comment: We just leave Node1Ext with its original value. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. Please give it a try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Node1Ext[. = 'X' or ../Node1 = 'X']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="(../Node1 = 'X') + 2 * (. = 'X')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```